# Executing npm tasks from root dir when package.json is in other location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, package.json

I know that this is not a good idea but i have a case where I have following directories structure and i cannot change that structure:

```
[projectRootDir]
    [src]
    [tests]
    [otherDirs]
    [configuration]
        package.json
        mocha.opts
        other files...
```

Is there a way to execute npm command without cd .. to [configuration] directory?

In package.json patterns for test files etc. are configured with following pattern:

> `test/**/*Test*.spec`

so I need to let the package.json know that root directory is in [projectRootDir].

node_modules should be inside [configuration] but this is not mandatory case if previous step can be done without this (can create symbolic link)

Comment: May I ask why it's not possible to place your `package.json` in your package root directory?  This is the idiomatic way to use `npm` and (if this is a Nodejs application) allows your backend source to `require()` modules downloaded by `npm install` without using paths.

Comment: Sure. In root directory i have package.json which i can't replace. This package.json from root directory contains whole configuration with project dependencies, project tasks etc. In package.json in configuration dir we have only one task responsible for i.e. running tests. I know that it sounds weird but this is the case

Comment: Consider merging the two `package.json`'s if you really want the behavior you're after.  The features `npm` provides (setting the PATH to include `node_modules/.bin` and setting the working directory to the dirname of `package.json`'s path assumes that `package.json` is in the root directory of your project).  If it's not there, you'll need to work around this behavior as you've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a script like this:

`"test": "cd .. && mkdir testFolder"`

Answer (score 0):

with [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) you could create packages that could be run from root
with `lerna run command` that will run in every project inside the packages folder